# Firebase não detectando app cordova

Tags: firebase, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Ao realizar o procedimento de adicionar um aplicativo ao firebase (google-services.json),

no final, aparece isso para mim:

Estamos verificando se o app se conectou aos nossos servidores. Talvez seja necessário desinstalar o app e instalá-lo novamente.

MASSSSS... Estou com o aplicativo instalado no meu celular (da play store por sinal), porem, nada de ele identificar...

O que está acontecendo ?

Eu adicionei as coisas que me pediram.

```
<widget id="com.herot.eyes" version="1.0.2" ... >
...
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>    
...
```

google-services.json ->

```
"android_client_info": {
  "package_name": "com.herot.eyes"
}
```

What is happening ??